# Php Undefined index, when storing a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Problem: Need to store field value when doing this query on my database. Have a couple pages that's using this same syntax but for some odd reason this isn't cooperating..

HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="listPage.php">  
    <fieldset>  
    <legend>Pull some data</legend>  
    <label for="name">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="255" /> 
    <hr />  
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="find event" /> 
    </fieldset>  
    </form>
```

listPage.php

```
<?php

//CONNECT TO DATABASE
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="db";
$connection=mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

echo "NOT running...";

//STORE ALL DATA FROM PREVIOUS FORM
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

  $query="SELECT event FROM events WHERE event='$name'";  
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);

    echo "running...";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {  
    echo $row['event'] . " // ";
    echo "<br />";
  }  
}

mysql_close($connection);  
?>
```

Comment: 1. You should escape the `$name` variable`. 2. Why not create a script that just contains `phpinfo()`. Change the HTML to see what environment you list.php will be executed in by using this script instead. 3. CHeck that the connection to the db actually works!

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Ed Heal, but it seems that it's not even passing the variable to list.php. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Starboy does list.php output nothing at all? Do you have `display_errors` turned on?

Comment: @Michael it did throw a undefined index error when I would go to store _POST name, but I have a feeling that was because nothing was getting passed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the post value is set before doing anything with it.  (Also, don't forget to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on it).

It may not be set if this code occurs on the page when it initially loads or is refreshed after having data posted to it.

```
// Don't attempt any of this unless you actually have a $_POST value
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

  $query="SELECT event FROM events WHERE event='$name'";  
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {  
    echo $row['event'] . " // ";
    echo "<br />";
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, and it seems that I'm not even getting the value passed (to list.php) once I hit submit... Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Starboy `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of `list.php`? Also, is it realy `list.php` or `List.php`? On many systems that matters

Comment: I updated the code with your recommendations and it doesn't even go through that if statement. Also added the var_dump($_POST) on list.php and nothing even came out. Also changed list.php to listPage.php just to see if that would do anything but had no luck.

Comment: I updated my first post with your input, still not receiving any data into $name, after putting data within the form..

Comment: Are you seeing the `echo "NOT running...";` you added?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quickly find any documentation regarding possible reserved words for POST or html form variables, so I went to

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post

and changed `fname` field to `name`, (clicked `edit and click me button`) and the POST variable was not passed or recognized.

So you might consider changing the name of your field to something other than `name`.